# Node.js MongoDB driver cursor does not count correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count

I'm having issues using MongoDB Node.js native driver version 2.2.29.

This is the code I'm running:

```
let cursor = db.collection( 'log' )
               .find({timestamp: { '$lte': 1498556839 }})
               .sort( { create_date_ttl: -1 } )
               .limit( 3 );
```

If I now run `cursor.count()` and handle the Promise I see the count is giving me 56 records instead of 3 (the limit specified).

```
cursor.count().then( (count) => {
   // count here is 56
});
```

However if I run `cursor.count( function (err, count) {})` using callbacks, the count is correct only 3 records.

```
cursor.count( function (err, count) {
  // count here is 3 according to the limit specified.
});
```

Does anybody having same issue or can someone explain me how is this possible? Maybe I'm missing something, but seems to be ok according with the official [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#count).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More interesting would be the result of the plain query with the promise rather than applying the count. Do all documents return then? Because that would imply a bug where the `.sort()` and `.limit()` modifiers are not being applied in the returned promise.

Comment: Yep. Read the documentation. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#count. The signature actually says you need to set the first argument in this context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Explicity set first argument ( `applySkipLimit` ) to true, and then `skip` and `limit` will be appilied.

```
cursor.count(true).then( (count) => {
   // count here will be 3
});
```

It seems documentation is unclarified, because there is written that true should be default value. As mentioned in comment it is behaviour of callback.

Comment: Actually the documentation is spot on, and tells you to do this. First option is `applySkipLimit` Link above. But yes this is correct. I suppose the "clarification" is *"default with a callback"* which is not what the documentation says.

Comment: Thanks Neil for clarification, yeah I think was not clear enough in the documentation.